# attempting to unlock all of phpmyadmin's features, sql query to gove pma user access to db generating error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

folowing a tutorial on unlocking the additional featers in phpMyAdmin ver 4.1.13

already added the pma user to the users database and even added said user to the config file... trying to run the query from the tutorial:

```
GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (
Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv,
File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv,
Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv,
Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv
) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv)
ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

gives me the 1146 error on line 1 where it claims that Mysql.HOST does not exist.... anybody know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You could do something like this... `GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';`

Comment: tried it... didnt unlock the additional features, but the query did run successfully

Comment: You then usually need to flush privileges, or logout then log back in.

Comment: tried flushing... didnt work... and how do i logout of phpmyadmin on wamp?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. I don't use phpMyAdmin. I use HeidiSQL http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: okay. upgraded myphp admin to a newer version. that one has a log in/logout page. it worked. thanks

Comment: Please show us a link to the tutorial you're using so we can see what it's telling you.